# Successive Ajax queries return old information

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

many thanks in advance.

Scenario: 
I am trying to query a mySQL database via jQuery and AJAX with multiple fields. The first search runs properly. Upon updating the fields and re-searching, the data from the original search is displayed, no update.

What I've tried:
Initially, I thought this may be a caching issue, so I have set cache: false.
I thought perhaps data was being concatenated in my target div, so I added a line to make my target div ('#inserted_item_data').html('') equal to a blank string so it's clean.
(Now showing my total noob-ness) I have even tried to add a line in the 'success:' parameter that (maybe?) makes the data array empty: data: {}; (I don't know if it that works like that, but I gave it a shot).

So without further Adu, my terrible code :

```
//students_get.php
...
<input class="input" type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" value="">
<input class="input" type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" value="">
<select name="residency" id="residency">
<option value="">---</option>
    <option value="Resident">Resident</option>
    <option value="Non-Resident">Non-Resident</option>
    <option value="AB540">AB540</option>
</select>
...
<input type="button" name="search" id="btnSearch" value="search">
<div style="width:60%; margin:0 auto;" id="inserted_item_data"></div>

...

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

       //@TODO Alternatively research stringify or serialize funcs
        var first_name = $('#first_name').val();
        var last_name = $('#last_name').val();
        var residency = $('#residency').val();

        $('#btnSearch').click(function () {
        $('#inserted_item_data').html('');
        console.log("Item Data Cleared");


        function fetch_item_data() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "students_get_fetch.php",
                method: "POST",
                cache: false, //disallowing cache
                data: {
                    first_name: first_name,
                    last_name: last_name,
                    residency: residency
                },

                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                    $('#inserted_item_data').html(data);
                    data: {}; //let's try emptying this array???
                }
            })
        }
         fetch_item_data();

    });





});
```

//students_get_fetch.php
//My fetch php code

```
*<?php
//fetch.php
$connect = mysqli_connect("webdev-2", "jhunt", "1234", "test");

$first_name = $_POST["first_name"];
$last_name = $_POST["last_name"];
$residency = $_POST["residency"];

$output = '';
//$query = "SELECT * FROM students ORDER BY last_name DESC";
$query = "SELECT * FROM students WHERE 
last_name LIKE '%". $last_name . "%' AND 
first_name LIKE '%". $first_name . "%' AND 
residency LIKE '%". $residency . "%' ";

$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
$output = '<br /><h3 align="center">Student (Quick Look)</h3><table class="table table-bordered table-striped"><tr><th width="31%">First Name</th><th width="31%">Last Name</th><th width="31%">Residency</th><th width="6%">Detail</th></tr>';


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
 $output .= '
 <tr>
  <td>'.$row["first_name"].'</td>
  <td>'.$row["last_name"].'</td>
  <td>'.$row["residency"].'</td>
  <td>'.$row["id"].'</td>
  </tr>
 ';
}
$output .= '</table>';
echo $output;
?>*
```

Highly appreciative of any guidance you could provide. Of course, symantical and best practices that I am most certainly missing.
Thank you kindly,
J

Comment: You could also eliminate the `function fetch_item_data() {` wrap, as its inside your click handler. Kind of needless to redefine that function and call it within the click event.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out to me IncredibleHat, appreciate your comments/critiques.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're fetching the values of the inputs and assigning them to variables when the page loads, but you *never check the values again*.

Each time you click the button, you're simply re-using the stale values that were present when the page loaded.

By moving your variable assignments *inside* the click event, they will use the *current* values of the inputs, rather than the values at the time of page load.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#btnSearch').click(function () {
        var first_name = $('#first_name').val();
        var last_name = $('#last_name').val();
        var residency = $('#residency').val();

        fetch_item_data(first_name, last_name, residency);
    });

});

function fetch_item_data(first_name, last_name, residency) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "students_get_fetch.php",
        method: "POST",
        cache: false, //disallowing cache
        data: {
            first_name: first_name,
            last_name: last_name,
            residency: residency
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
            $('#inserted_item_data').html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

I've also made some minor syntactic corrections. As IncredibleHat pointed out above, you probably want to declare `fetch_item_data` elsewhere. Additionally, your `data: {}` line is not necessary, nor valid.

Comment: Anyone care to elaborate as to why they've downvoted my answer? If there's something wrong, I'd love to fix it, however I can't do that if I don't know what it is.

Comment: I upvoted because this is a solution to the problem as described.

Comment: Actually that recent edit, puts those variables out of scope... ?

Comment: Success!!! Tyler Roper and @IncredibleHat, thank you so much for, not only the very timely response but also the explanation. Looking now at your edits, it does really make a lot of sense, 'why' my solution was evading me. I truly appreciate your time and expertise.